# Not able to pass event in Salesforce from Child to Parent

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Hi I am trying to pass a custom event from child to parent, but getting strange error.

Event Code :-

```
const passEventr = new CustomEvent('recordselection', {  
     detail: { selectedRecordId: this.selectedRecordId, selectedValue: this.selectedValue }  
    });
```

Reciver  :- `onrecordselection={onAccountSelection}`  --  HTML

JS  :-

```
onAccountSelection(event){
        console.log('>>>Event =='+JSON.stringify(event));
        console.log('I am Here');
        this.accountName = event.detail.selectedValue;  
        this.accountRecordId = event.detail.selectedRecordId;
}
```

in console window I am getting  -  >>>Event =={"isTrusted":false,"composed":false}

Comment: What do you see if you try `console.log(event.detail.selectedValue);`?

Comment: Please check what are you getting when you add the console as suggested above. Also share how are you triggering the event? Is it `this.dispatchEvent` or `window.dispatchEvent`, if its this can you try adding `bubbles: true, composed: true`

Comment: Values are coming but complete event is not been printed